# Compare two columns by splitting and changing data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question that a little bit confusing.
In my case there are two columns that I have to compare (ITIN and dateOfBirth)

```
column1              column2
30305852180137       03.05.1985
```

From second number of column1 till 7th number is also date
03(day), 05(month), 85(last two numbers of year). Thanks to all answers

Comment: What is the data type of the two columns?

Comment: column1 is number, column2 is date

Answer (score 1):

That depends on datatypes. I *presumed* that both are strings stored in VARCHAR2. In that case, convert them both to date using appropriate format mask. Once you're done, it is easy to compare them.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    -- string vs. string
  3    (select '30305852180137', '03.05.1985' from dual)
  4  select to_date(substr(col1, 2, 6), 'ddmmrr') dat1,
  5         to_date(col2, 'dd.mm.yyyy') dat2
  6  from test;

DAT1       DAT2
---------- ----------
03.05.1985 03.05.1985
```

If - as commented - it is about number and date, not a big difference:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    -- number vs. date
  3    (select 30305852180137, date '1985-05-03' from dual)
  4  select to_date(substr(to_char(col1), 2, 6), 'ddmmrr') dat1,
  5         col2 as dat2
  6  from test;

DAT1       DAT2
---------- ----------
03.05.1985 03.05.1985
```

Comment: OK, doesn't change much. I added that example as well.

Comment: but what is year is bigger than 2000 should i put yy instead of rr

Comment: You're welcome. `RR` will work till 2050. Basically, you should use 4 digits for years, not 2. Did Y2K bug teach you nothing?

Comment: all that kind of date has been stored. Only thing that i should remove wrong stores. Anyway I have understood Y2K from google.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the values to strings:

```
where substr(column1, 2, 6) = to_char(column2, 'DDMMYY')
```